# Separador de mil en php o mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta donde muestra los valores numéricos con separador de mil (1,500) y tengo dos problemas:

1. Cuando abro la ventana modal para editar los valores me muestra los valores con el separador de mil, pero si edito el valor de un campo y el otro no el campo no editado me lo formatea y sólo me muestra el número que está al lado izquierdo del separador
2. Cuando sumo todos los valores me suma sólo los números que están a la izquierda del separador. El dato en la db es decimal(19,2) y el tipo en el input es number.

Consulta que trae los valores

```
  SELECT FORMAT(apostado,'Currency') as apostado, FORMAT(ganado,'Currency') as ganado FROM apuesta
```

Consulta que suma los valores de apostado

```
SELECT sum(FORMAT(apostado,'Currency')) as apostado FROM apuesta
```

algunas imágenes del problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna solución.....

Código para actualizar.

```js
$id_apuesta = $_POST['id_apuesta'];
$apostado = $_POST['apostado'];
$ganado = $_POST['ganado'];

$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE apuesta SET apostado='$apostado', ganado='$ganado' WHERE id_apuesta=$id_apuesta");


<script>
            $('#editUsu').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                var recipient0 = button.data('id_apuesta')
                var recipient1 = button.data('apostado')
                var recipient2 = button.data('ganado');

                var modal = $(this)
                modal.find('.modal-body #id_apuesta').val(recipient0)
                modal.find('.modal-body #valor_apostado').val(recipient1)
                modal.find('.modal-body #valor_ganado').val(recipient2);
            });
        </script>
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">                      
                            <form action="actualizar_apuesta.php" method="POST">    
                                <input  id="id_apuesta" name="id_apuesta" type="hidden" ></input>  

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">    
                                            <label for="apostado" class="form-control-label">Valor Apostado *</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">    
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-5-1"></i>
                                                </span> 
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apostado" name="apostado"  value="<?php echo $row['apostado']; ?>" >
                                            </div>                                                                                     
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                                               
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="ganado" class="form-control-label">Valor Ganado *</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">    
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                                </span>   
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ganado" name="ganado" value="<?php echo $row['ganado']; ?>" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: La solución al segundo problema es realizar el formato una vez que se hizo la suma. `SELECT FORMAT(sum(apostado), 2) as apostado FROM apuesta;`.  Y sobre el primer problema, ¿podrías compartir tu código `HTML/PHP` para dar una respuesta más acertada y específica?

Comment: Hola amigo, su respuesta al segundo problema sirvió para dar solución a ese problema. Actualicé la pregunta para agregar el código para resolver el primer problema.

Comment: yo te recomendaría tomar cada valor y guardarlo como floar(Decimal y no como un valor monetario), luego cuando obtienes el dato puedes utilizarlo para hacer cálculos ya que es un float siempre que vayas a imprimir uno de estos numero entonces lo pasas por la funcion correspondiente: string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," ) y te dara las comas separadoras de miles

Comment: El problema es la coma, si quieres humanizar los numeros, solo lo haria antes de dibujarlos con algun snippet o funcion que se encargue de hacerlo, despues quitaria todos los caracteres extraños ejemplo comas a la hora de trabajar con ellos.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql no tiene ningún campo numérico  que intérprete o utilice el separador de miles por lo que se debe de evitar a la hora de insertar o modificar un campo, solo se debería usar para formatear los datos al mostrarlos y nada más.

PHP provee la función n**umber_format()** para esto, mi recomendación es que quites el **FORMAT()** de tus consultas.

```
SELECT apostado, ganado FROM apuesta

SELECT sum(apostado) as apostado FROM apuesta
```

Y formatees solo donde sea necesario con number_format() de php

```
// Notación  inglesa
echo number_format($numero, 2, '.', ',');
// ejemplo 1,234.56
```

Más info en la documentación:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php

Obviamente deberías evitar formatear los valores de los input.

Si en algún caso quieres mantener el formato de los input deberás eliminar los caracteres que no forman parte del número cuando recibes los datos, por ejemplo con str_replace()

```
$numero = '1,234.56';
$numero = str_replace(',', '', $número); 
// 1234.56
```

Documentación de str_replace()

http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php