# función de separación de miles

Tags: php

buen dia, me gustaria que me ayudaran a utilizar la funcion de formato de numeros para separar las cantidades en miles, dispongo del siguiente codigo

```
 <?php
            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
            $link = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=Client_cxp', 'root', '');
            foreach ($link->query("SELECT * FROM client_cartera WHERE Codigo_cliente = '$codigo'") as $row){
          ?>
          <?php echo $row['Codigo_cliente']?>
        <td><?php echo $row['Nom_client']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Plazo_credito']?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['Cartera_vencida']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Cartera_actual']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Cartera_total']?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['Limit_credito']?></td>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
```

En que parte podría agregar la función?

Comment: cual función?...

Comment: Revisa la respuesta de esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23179/como-hacer-que-mi-input-text-tenga-separador-de-miles-y-decimales-en-jquery

Comment: Puedes revisar esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/88582/38103

Answer (score 0):

No se a que hacen referencia los demás datos que manejas, pero por ejemplo supongo que sí que lo querrás en el dato "limit_credito". En este caso podrías utilizar la función "number_format":

```
echo number_format($row['Limit_credito']);
```

Puedes elegir los separadores de decimales y miles, así:

number_format($numero,numero_de_decimales,separador_decimal,separador_miles);

Osea:

```
number_format('12345.678', 2, ',', '.');
```

Imprimirá: 12.345,68

Porque hemos elegido una precisión de 2 decimales, separador de coma para los decimales y separador de punto para los millares.

Aquí tienes la [info del manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php). Echale también un vistazo a la función [money_format](http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php), que a lo mejor también te resulta útil.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por el aporte!! :)

Comment: Sera que puedo crear dos condiciones a ese codigo? para realizar la comparacion de dos campos e imprimir un mensaje?

Comment: @ZephyrotGM, perdona, no te acabo de entender...